# Loop through a row until blank

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have the code below that does the following.

It finds the text “EE Only” in column A and records the row number.

It then adds four rectangles with the first one in the recorded row number and the other three in the three rows below.

It then formats the rectangles with no fill and a black border.

I have dim c as Integer and c = 2.  I then use that as the column.   So far everything is working as it should.  The problem I’m having is that I need the column number to increase by one for every column after B that has something in row 3.  In other words; the first set of shapes will always be in column B.  After that if there is something in C3 then I need the column number to be increase by 1 and the shapes added to column C.  If something is in D3 increase c by 1 and add shapes to column D and so forth.  The first time row 3 is blank the loop would stop.

I’ve tried a couple of different things and I’m at a completely loss.  The other issue I’m having is, if I run the code with c = 2 the shapes are formatted properly.  If I then leave those shapes and manually change to c = 3 and run the code again, the new set of shapes have a blue fill.  Again, tried everything I could find and nothing works.

```
Sub AddShapes()
Const TextToFind As String = "EE Only"
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim RowNum As Range

Dim SSLeft As Double
Dim SSTop As Double
Dim SS As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim c As Integer
c = 2

Set RowNum = ws.Range("A:A").Find(what:=TextToFind, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set SS = Cells(RowNum.Row, c)
SSLeft = Cells(RowNum.Row, c).Left + (Cells(RowNum.Row, c).Width) / 4

'Add four rectangles
Dim y As Integer
For y = 0 To 3
    SSTop = Cells(RowNum.Row + y, c).Top + ((Cells(RowNum.Row + y, c).Height) / 2) - 5
    Call ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, SSLeft, SSTop, 10, 10)
Next

'Format them

ws.DrawingObjects.Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Weight = 1
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't 100% sure about your requirements, but here's my best interpretation of it. Not I defined a new subroutine for the rectangles section, see comments for details

```
Sub AddShapes()
    Const TextToFind As String = "EE Only"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim RowNum As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim c As Integer
    c = 2

    Set RowNum = ws.Range("A:A").Find(what:=TextToFind, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Call Rectangles(RowNum.row, c, ws) ' call the rectangles function for our first instance

    c = c+1 ' increment the column by one so we're not on the same column

    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(3,c).Value) 'Loop through each column until the 3rd row is empty
        Call Rectangles(3,c,ws) ' call our rectangles function on the 3rd row in the current column (c)
        c=c+1 ' increment the column
    Loop

End Sub

Sub Rectangles(row As Integer, c As Integer, ws As Worksheet) ' we define a separate sub to draw the rectangles so that we can call it again and again
    Dim SSLeft As Double
    Dim SSTop As Double
    Dim SS As Range
    Set SS = Cells(row, c)
    SSLeft = Cells(row, c).Left + (Cells(row, c).Width) / 4

    'Add four rectangles
    Dim y As Integer
    For y = 0 To 3
        SSTop = Cells(row + y, c).Top + ((Cells(row + y, c).Height) / 2) - 5
        Call ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, SSLeft, SSTop, 10, 10)
    Next

    'Format them

    ws.DrawingObjects.Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 1
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.  I just tried running this and I'm getting a error in Sub Rectangles on the line Set SS = Cells(row, c)  c shows as empty.  I'm not sure how to correct this.

Comment: As always, I posted my followup questions and then figured it out.  I changed "col as Integer" to "c as Integer" and it ran through with no errors.  The second column isn't placing them shapes in the right place.  Where is finds "EE Only", but I'll spend some more time and try and figure it out.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: ahh yes my apologies I forgot to rename that variable, glad you figured it out!